# Changing MySQL range partition clause

Tags: mysql, range, partitioning, alter

I have a table created with range partitioning implemented. The clause is :

```
    ...partition by range (DAYOFMONTH(day)) 
   (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
    ...
    PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (31)
    );
```

Now, I wish to change the partitioning condition to

```
   .... partition by range (DAYOFMONTH(day) mod 31)
```

with the rest of individual partition definitions remaining the same.  Is it possible to do so by any ALTER TABLE command or do I have to remove partitioning first and recreate partitions with the new condition?
I researched quite a lot about this but all information found was about reorganizing individual partitions.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

And you are saying following won't work for you ? I tried on version 5.6.10 successfully !

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
   PARTITION BY RANGE( DAYOFMONTH(day) mod 31 ) (
   PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
   PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2),
   PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3),
   PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (4),
   ...
   PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (31)
);
```